# extract a column from a matrix in a list in R

Tags: r

I have a list of 100 elements. Each element is a list. And this list has two elements in them. One is just a key another is a matrix. This matrix has 5 columns in it. I am trying to extract one column from each of these matrices for all the elements. So basically I would have 100 matrices again as an element of the list. This is how the list looks like

```
a[[1]]
     [[1]]
          [1] "keyid"

      [[2]] 
              [,1]                [,2]          [,3]    [,4]    [,5]
          [1,] "1329397986.572332" "x" "y" "z" "a"
          [2,] "1329242747.368294" "x" "y" "z" "a"
          [3,] "1329194224.351232 "x" "y" "z" "a"
```

So what you can see here is a is a list and it has 100 elements. Each element is a list of 2 elements. I am currently interested only in the second element. The second element has a matrix. I would like to extract the first column of this matrix. Just to see if I can extract the column into a vector I can do

```
a[[1]][[2]][,1]
```

and I get all the values as a vector, as follows.

```
a[[1]][[2]][,1]  
       [1] "1329397986.572332" "1329242747.368294" "1329194224.351232"
```

But when I do

```
 x <- lapply(a,function(r){r[[2]][,1]})
```

the following is the error I get.

```
> x <- lapply(a, function(r){r[[2]][,1]})
Error in r[[2]][, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

I am not sure why I am getting that. I checked the dimensions of the matrix element.

```
> dim(a[[1]][[2]])
  [1] 52  5
```

and it looks correct. So I am not sure where the error is.

dput(a) gives

```
dput(a)
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] "keyid"

[[1]][[2]]
  [,1]                [,2]          [,3]    [,4]    [,5]
[1,] "1329397986.572332" "x"   "y"     "z"     "a"
[2,] "1329242747.368294" "x"   "y"     "z"     "a"
[3,] "1329194224.351232" "x"   "y"     "z"     "a"

[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] "keyid"

[[2]][[2]]
  [,1]                [,2]          [,3]    [,4]    [,5]
[1,] "1329397986.572332" "x"   "y"     "z"     "a"
[2,] "1329242747.368294" "x"   "y"     "z"     "a"
[3,] "1329194224.351232" "x"   "y"     "z"     "a"

...

[[100]]
[[100]][[1]]
[1] "keyid"

[[100]][[2]]
  [,1]                [,2]          [,3]    [,4]    [,5]
[1,] "1329397986.572332" "x"   "y"     "z"     "a"
[2,] "1329242747.368294" "x"   "y"     "z"     "a"
[3,] "1329194224.351232" "x"   "y"     "z"     "a"
```

Comment: can you post output of `dput(a)` here.. Hard to understand what's going on without reproducing on our end.

Comment: `dput(a)` is going to be pretty large, with 100 list entries.  I suspect that one of them is malformed.

Comment: `dput(a)` does *not* give that!

Comment: @MatthewLundberg I generated all the matrices using the same code. Do you think there still is a possibility of it being malformed? I guess I will have to run a for loop all through a and then see which one renders an error. That would be the one.

Comment: What does `sapply(a, function(x)is.matrix(x[[2]]))` give you? Any `FALSE`?

Comment: @MatthewLundberg dput does give a lot more.. but I trimmed it to not put up 20000 lines of output. =)

Comment: `dput` gives a completely different format.  Perhaps `options(error=recover)` would be appropriate, as you seem to be in Circle 8.

Comment: @flodel Thanks for that. I have about 10 of them that are giving out false. I did check as to why it was doing that and it seems like there is only one row in the matrix. Would that be the problem? Having one row in a matrix is not considered a matrix?

Comment: @Bartha, if you are creating these matrices by subsetting from a bigger matrix using `[`, add the `drop = FALSE` option. By default, `[` will return a vector (not a matrix) if you extract a single row or column from a matrix.

Comment: Hi Bartha, the reason folks are interested in the actual output of `dput(a)` as opposed to what you have posted is that the output can easily be copied and pasted right into our session, thus making it easier for folks to handle and manipulate your data without needing to type it in by hand.

Comment: All, apologies for the morphed and the truncated dput(a). I just put it in this format as I thought that I would be violating some policy where by posting the output that   goes upwards of 20 thounsand lines.

Comment: If you had just posted the output of `dput(head(a))` people would have been completely satisfied.

Answer (score 12):

This seems a perfect case for the little-used function `rapply`.

Until a reproducible example is posted, I will post this as a possible solution

```
set.seed(1)
# a possible reproducible example
a <- replicate(5, list('a', matrix(runif(10), ncol=5)), simplify = FALSE)

# the first column
a1 <- rapply(a, classes = 'matrix', how = 'list', f = function(x) x[, 1, drop = FALSE]) 
# a second `lapply` is required to drop `NULL` entries

a1Only <- lapply(a1, Filter, f = Negate(is.null))
```

Comment: +1 You just cut down some annoying code by introducing rapply. Didn't even know it existed!

Comment: I don't think this produces a similarly constituted list ... no keyid element.

Comment: @Dwin replace `'a'` with `'keyid'`?

Comment: I guess. The strategy of NULL-ing out every non-matrix and then collapsing seems kludgy to me. What if there were a third item that was a different sized matrix?

Comment: I'll agree that this is specific to the case where there is only one matrix entry per top level element.

Comment: If you use how = 'replace' then the keyid (a) items are retained. If you wanted this you could then not run the lapply step.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
a <- list(list("keyid", structure(c("1329397986.572332", "1329242747.368294", 
"1329194224.351232", "x", "x", "x", "y", "y", "y", "z", "z", 
"z", "a", "a", "a"), .Dim = c(3L, 5L))), list("keyid", structure(c("1329397986.572332", 
"1329242747.368294", "1329194224.351232", "x", "x", "x", "y", 
"y", "y", "z", "z", "z", "a", "a", "a"), .Dim = c(3L, 5L))))

sapply( lapply(a, "[[" , 2) , "[", TRUE, 1)
     [,1]                [,2]               
[1,] "1329397986.572332" "1329397986.572332"
[2,] "1329242747.368294" "1329242747.368294"
[3,] "1329194224.351232" "1329194224.351232"
```

Explanation: the inner `lapply` pulls out the second element in each sublist, passing it on to the outer `sapply`. The (outer) `sapply` uses `[` to pull out the first column from each of the objects passed to it. Since `[` is a primitive function, .i.e. one that uses positional arguments only,  you do need to use a placeholder which is the purpose for supplying the "TRUE" argument. It's purpose is to "push" the "1" over into second argument position and thereby make it a column-selector rather than a row-selector.